# How do i use link_to in order to link to an index controller but listing only those objects with a specific attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do i use link_to in order to link to an index controller but listing only those objects with a specific attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
link_to 'Widgets', widgets_path, :some_attr => 'meep'
```

Then, in WidgetsController#index, find_by_some_attr(params['some_attr']).

Of course, if you ask a more specific question you might get a more specific answer.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness..


 link_to "widgets", widgets_path, :proion => 'Μικρόμετρο'  

and in controller like this?  

@widgets = Widget.find_all_by_proion(params['proion'])

Thanks anyway!

Comment: `link_to 'Widgets', widgets_path, :attr1 => 'foo', :attr2 => 'bar'` which will let you call `Widget.find_all_by_attr1_and_attr2(params[:attr1], params[:attr2])` .. is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes! However now if the controller receives only 1 attibute it just produces null. Is this because the find_all_by_attr1_and_attr2 produces an AND operator in SQL?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps it would help to read some documentation :) This is a good place to start for understanding AR: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html